# Using getJSON to post JSON object to PHP page and also retrieve a JSON object

Tags: php, jquery, json, getjson

I am trying to build an HTML5 application that heavily leverages JSON for data access.  In several instances, I would like to use the getJSON object (using JavaScript and JQuery) to post a JSON object to a PHP page.  That PHP page will then grab the JSON object, do some business logic, and then return a separate JSON object to the calling page.

I can get a valid JSON object returned to the calling page, but I can't seem to grab the JSON object that I passed in the original request.  I've tried $_GET, $_POST and several other options.  All to no avail.

Here is my code on the original page.  It is very simple - when a user clicks the button we do an AJAX call that passes a JSON object to the page called receive_jason.php.  This page is supposed to evaluate the JSON object passed in and return another JSON object to the original page.

PAGE 1:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
function StartPost()
{
var strJSON = '{"id":"3","artist":"The Beatles","alblum":"White Alblum"}';
var jsonURL = "receive_json.php";

$.getJSON(  jsonURL, 
            strJSON, 
            function(data) {
                var items = [];

                responseMsg     = data["success"];
                alert(responseMsg);

    });

}

</script>

<body>
     <input type="button" name="Post Data" value="Post Data" onClick="StartPost();">
</body>

</html>
```

And here is the PHP code on the receive_json.php page...

```
<?php
    $incomingData = $_GET['artist'];
    $myText =(string) $incomingData;
    echo "{\"success\":\"" . strlen($myText) . "\"}";
?>
```

Just to be clear, the getJSON call works and I do receive a valid JSON call on the return.  But I can't access the JSON object that I am passing in.

My questions....

1) Is this just a simple syntax error that I can fix?

2) Is getJSON even the right function for this task?

3) Is there an easy way for me to debug getJSON requests so I can see what is happening on the page?

Comment: As mentioned by SLaks, if you want to use POST, use `$.ajax`. To be honest, I'm so pleased with `.ajax()` syntax that it's all I use anyhow. ;-) Remember on the server side, that if you're POSTing JSON, you're posting a string to a parameter. It's not inherently a "JSON object", you will need to use PHP to decode into a usable object. Does PHP have native JSON parsing utilities?

Comment: @Greg Pettit - See json_encode and json_decode to handle JSON in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` sends GET requests.

You need to use `$.ajax` with `method: "POST"` and `type: "json"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "yourfile_orserverfile.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                  //whatever your data is
                }
                datatype: "json",
                success: function (status) {
                    if (status.success == false) {
                        //alert a failure message
                    } else {
                        //alert a success message
                    }
                }
            });
```